# Component Reference on click in Angular-4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am adding the different component on click, and user can add any component and also remove it but to remove a component how can I get the reference of component where user click is there any way to get the component reference on click in angular-4.
here is sample components which are loading in **`app.component.ts`**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'question-paragraph',
  template: `<div class="form-group container">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>`,
})
export class QuestionParagraphComponent { }

@Component({
  selector: 'question-image',
  template: `<div class="form-group container">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
      <p>Upload Image</p>
      <input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" />
    </form>
  </div>`,
})
export class QuestionImageComponent { }
```

And that is the function which add them

```
if (item=='question') {
      this.addService.appendComponentToBody(QuestionDetailComponent);
      this.removeComponent(this.sg[this.sg['question_id']]);
    } else if (item=='image') {
      this.addService.appendComponentToBody(QuestionImageComponent);
      this.removeComponent(this.sg[this.sg['question_id']]);
      let componentRef = this.addService.appendComponentToBody(QuestionTypeComponent);
      this.sg['ComRef'] = componentRef;
    }
```

I know the function to remove the component only if I know its reference

```
removeComponent(componentRef){
    this.appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
    componentRef.destroy();
  }
```

Can anybody please tell me how to get the reference of a component on click, thanks.

Comment: Why do you add components to the page in the first place. The template should do that for you. Just use an ngFor iterating through your items, and inside the ngFor, use ngIf to display a question component if the item type is a question, and an image component if the item type is an image. To remove a component, just remove the item from the array. And ngFor will remove the matching component for you. That's the basic principle of angular.

Comment: because ngFor will iterate on a specific template but user can load any component he wants, so I have to get that component reference to remove it, in above it just example, it could be forty to fifty different component, I can't iterate on them and check for every input user can made. thanks

Comment: Your two if blocks in your code hardcode two types of component. So I don't see how "user can load any component he wants". I just suggest doing the same thing in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you add a component dynamically you are adding it to a parent element. You can add a `@ViewChildren` to your component where you want the reference and access its children. The second parameter there is of type `ViewContainerRef` which is what you want to access dynamically added children:

```
 @ViewChildren(DynamicComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef }) components: QueryList<DynamicComponent>
```

Also you could have used the return value from `createComponent` method you used as well.

**UPDATE:**
You can subscribe to changes from your components reference as well:

```
this.components.changes().subscribe(x=> console.log(x));
```